# Javascript clone duplicating div's in increments

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently working on a web page and one of the features is that it allows users to add an extra div (which already exists) to the page by clicking on an image. The page is designed using Bootstrap 3.0

This div already exists and when the image is pressed, it duplicates the div. This works fine if the user wants to duplicate the div once, but if they try to duplicate it twice, then the div is duplicated 4 times, and if they try it 3 times, the div is duplicating 8 times.

Below is my Javascript code for duplicating the div -

```
function addRow() {
  var row = document.getElementById("row-to-clone");
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);

  row.appendChild(clone);
}
```

The row-to-clone is just the ID of the div that I want to duplicate, but I don't know why it is duplicating it more than once. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You're creating elements with the same ID, which is invalid, but it shouldn't cause multiplying as `getElementById` generally only returns the first matching element anyway. How exactly is the `addRow` function called ?

Comment: You're appending the clone into the row you're cloning. The next time you clone it you're cloning them both, etc.

Comment: @ray - good eyes, it should be `row.parentNode.appendChild(clone);`

Comment: @adeneo Can you explain please why it's invalid? Sorry I'm relatively new to Javascript. It's being called like this - `<img src="images/plus-symbol.png" onclick = "addRow()" class = "plus-img" title = "Add"/>` edit - your second reply is working, it's only duplicating one at a time now, thank you!

Comment: Its invalid because an id is not supposed to be used more than once in one page. That's why its called ID -> Identification of an element.

Comment: ^ that, using the same ID for multiple elements is invalid HTML.

Comment: Yes it would be better as it would at least not be invalid, but that won't solve your problem either.

Comment: Oh...actually I didn't know that you have already implemented it. Yes @adeneo's is the correct solution.

Comment: For that you can use the `lastChild` property. For reference -> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_lastchild.asp

Comment: I went to the data explorer section but couldn't find what you said...so could you please give a more direct pointer or the code in which you're having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're appending the cloned row as a child of the original row. You think you're doing this:

```
+-----+
|  A  |
+-----+
+-----+
|  A' |
+-----+
```

...but you're actually doing this:

```
+-------+
|   A   |
|+-----+|
||  A' ||
|+-----+|
+-------+
```

When you clone *A* a second time, you're getting *A* and all of its children, which includes *A'*, ergo four rows.

To append the clone after the original, do this instead:

```
row.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, row.nextSibling);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, yeah I thought I was doing what you have in the first diagram. Also, I tried your suggestion but nothing happens when I attempt to clone the row. Do I need to rename parentDiv?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. It's supposed to be `parentNode`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the new div to the parent of `row` not to the `row` itself.

```
function addRow() {
  var row = document.getElementById("row-to-clone");

  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);

  row.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbn71bzn/)